# Vue check multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to check multiple radio buttons in vue but it's not working. Normal html lets you check multiple radio buttons if the name attributes are different but it isn't working in vue

```js
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        selected: []
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-group label="Individual radios">
      <b-form-radio v-model="selected" name="some-radios0" value="A">Option A</b-form-radio>
      <b-form-radio v-model="selected" name="some-radios1" value="B">Option B</b-form-radio>
    </b-form-group>

    <div class="mt-3">Selected: <strong>{{ selected }}</strong></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

So I changed the name attributes but it still isn't working. This is so unlikely.

Comment: well, you should use checkboxes not radio buttons...

Comment: @Ifaruki I tried that and got this error --> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "checked". Expected Array, got String with value "".

found in

---> <BFormCheckboxGroup>

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check multiple checkboxes then you should use `b-form-checkbox-group`

Here is a link to the documentation : https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-checkbox

Here is your code modified :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-group label="Checkboxes">
      <b-form-checkbox-group v-model="selected" name="some-radios">
        <b-form-checkbox value="A">Option A</b-form-checkbox>
        <b-form-checkbox value="B">Option B</b-form-checkbox>
      </b-form-checkbox-group>
    </b-form-group>

    <div class="mt-3">Selected: <strong>{{ selected }}</strong></div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        selected: [], // Must be an array reference!
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```